# Configuring SSH with Keys in Slackware 13.0

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, slackware

The last day or so, I've been trying to figure out how to setup SSH on my Slackware box with public/private keys.

Somethings still confuses me:

- In the sshd_config file, should I use a relative reference or an absolute reference when setting the path for the AuthorizedKeysFile directive? I've read that it can be either or.

  Currently set to, AuthorizedKeysFile /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
- I'm pretty sure that when generating a key through ssh-keygen it should be generated on the client machine and the public key should be copied to the server and added into the authorized_keys file. Is this correct?
- I'm pretty sure that the permissions to the .ssh directory and
  authorized_keys file are correct.

  drw-------        .ssh
  drwx--x---        authorized_keys
  -rw----r--        known_hosts
- I've done a ps -e aux | grep sshd to see what user was running the sshd process. Here are the results: moros is a standard user account that i'm using to log into my box.

  root 5449 0.0 0.0 4112 0980 ? Ss 01:06 0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
  root 5574 0.0 0.1 6700 2020 ? Ss 15:22 0:00 sshd: moros [priv]
  root 5576 0.0 0.0 6700 1272 ? S  15:22 0:00 sshd: moros@pts/0
  root 5609 0.0 0.0 2204 0628 pts/0 S+ 15:42 0:00 grep sshd
- Here's what part of my sshd_config looks like

  Port 22
  Protocol 2

  SyslogFacility AUTH
  LogLevel VERBOSE

  PermitRootLogin yes
  RSAAuthentication yes
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  AuthorizedKeysFile /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

  PasswordAuthentication yes
  PermitEmptyPasswords no

  The rest of it is standard default values.

Anyway, there are a few things that I've been able to determine so far. I know that ssh is working because I can login from a client machine with a password for a valid user on the slackware machine. I've generated a ssh-keygen rsa style and copied the pub key to the server using scp. At the moment, I'm pretty sure that the authorized_keys is setup correctly. I did a cat file >> authroized_keys and added the pub key that I copied to the server. The file has the form of ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza..... for each line. I turned on VERBOSE logging to get as much information as possible. Last night, I saw in the log, "Failed publickey for moros from 'ip' port 'num' ssh2.

With that log message, I'm boiling the cause of the issue down to one of two things. Either sshd can not find my authorized_keys file and thus the reason for the failure of the key or that the permissions to either the .ssh folder or the authorized keys file are incorrect.

Has anyone run into similar problems with ssh keys and slackware in the past?

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, the AuthorizedKeysFile directive should state, .ssh/authorized_keys.
This now works when i login as some other than root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `AuthorizedKeysFile /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, you are telling `sshd` to go look for the key in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` for whomever is trying to connect. That can't work for anyone else than root. You should stick to the default of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The key pair can be generated anywhere. Simply, the public key should be present on the server to which you want to connect, and the private key on the client form which you are connecting.

The permissions are pretty messed up. They should look like:

```
drwx------- .ssh
-rw------- authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- known_hosts
```

`authorized_keys` should be a file, not a directory.

Also, make sure the permission of the private key are be `-rw-------`.

Comment: Should that be ~/.ssh/authorized_keys or .ssh/authorized_keys? Originally, the commented out directive had it as .ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: From the manual, the default is ` ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I've updated my sshd_config file and set the AuthorizedKeysFile to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. When i try to ssh as root from my mac, I'm able to get without being asked for the password. But when I try to log in as moros, it still asks me for a password. I've restarted sshd. I've copied the authorized_keys file from /root/.ssh/ to /home/moros/.ssh

Comment: the private key permission is -rw-------

Comment: authorized_keys in moros/.ssh is -rw------- and .ssh in moros is drwx------

Comment: moros in home looks like this: drwx------ 4 moros users 4096 2013-11-29 16:26 moros/. This could have something to do with my issue.

Comment: on the server, start `sshd` in debug mode: `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -e -p  1234` and then try to connect from the client with `ssh -p 1234 ...`. What does it say?

Comment: It keeps trying to access authroized keys file at /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: I updated the config file to use ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. sshd is running under root, when I did a ps -e aux | grep sshd. root /usr/sbin/sshd

Comment: Should /usr/sbin/sshd run under a different user?

Comment: Perhaps my user does not have the correct groups?

Comment: As a test, I created a new user, changed the authorized to point to my new user /theNewUser/.ssh/authorized_keys, then did /usr/sbin/sshd -d -e -p 1234. I tried the same experiment but with ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. The second experiment would always look at /root/.ssh/... Very wierd!

Comment: Thanks for the help damienfrancois, i was able to figure it out. It appears that in Slackware anyway, the authroizedKeysFile needs to be .ssh/authorized_keys not ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. That did the trick.

Comment: According to www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5 it states in the AuthorizedKeysFile that the default is either .ssh/authorized_keys or .ssh/authorized_keys2. I guess I should have looked there first. :)